# Merge and remove classes models in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, yolo

I have my own model with 3 classes. Also I want to use yolov5x.pt due to the best person recognition, but there are a lot of useless classes and it's too big (150M) for me. I opened *.pt file - it is a zip archive with binary data of classes: 0 - person, 1 - cars etc. I don't need these classes, so how can I open a model, remove unnecessary classes and merge with my own model?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't think you can change a pre-trained model like that (if you are indeed trying to change the pre-trained model). The general approach would be to use the backbone of the model and fine-tune it for your own usecase (there are lots of tutorials for that). However I don't think that would have a noticeable effect on the model size anyways since last layers don't usually make up the large portion of model size.